# Missing imap protocol tab within gmail

Tags: gmail-imap

I am helping my daughter to receive gmails using the Apple mail.  Currently, we are not able to set up her gmails through the Apple mail app on her macbook.  I went to her gmail settings but her pop/imap protocol tab is missing.  We do have a family link but making changes are not allowed as she is already over the age.  She doesn't want to delete her current gmail as she uses it for school, - her email is not part of a shool/work type of email.  It is an indepedent email.  Any tip or advise would be helpful as we don't know of any google call center.